# What's wrong in these 5 myriad ways of declaring/initializing constant-qualified pointers?(Taken from a dubious but popular book)

Tags: c, pointers, constants, qualifiers

My bad!!I had assumed that the following excerpt from a notorious yet wildly popular book is totally valid C.But only today I was pointed out that it's ridden with UB (though I am yet to find how come it's so).Hence here's that particular section from the book.You will be doing me and many other "victims" like me a great favor if you can point out in a numbered manner what is wrong or UB with each particular statement,and the appropriate corrections for those.

```
char *p = "Hello" ;  /* pointer is variable, so is string */ 
*p = 'M' ;  /* works */ 
p = "Bye" ;  /* works */ 


const char *q = "Hello" ;  /* string is fixed pointer is not */ 
*q = 'M' ;  /* error */ 
q = "Bye" ;  /* works */ 


char const *s = "Hello" ;  /* string is fixed pointer is not */ 
*s = 'M' ;  /* error */ 
s = "Bye" ;  /* works */ 


char * const t = "Hello" ;  /* pointer is fixed string is not */ 
*t = 'M' ;  /* works */    
t = "Bye" ;  /* error */ 


const char * const u = "Hello" ;  /* string is fixed so is pointer */ 
*u = 'M' ;  /* error */ 
u = "Bye" ;  /* error */
```

Comment: `char *p` should point to a non-const string. string literals are constants.

Comment: The `q` and `s` cases above are identical. `const char *` and `char const *` are the same type.

Comment: @mat Do me & others like me a real favor.Take a minute to post a detailed answer.

Comment: The only problems above are when you attempt to write to the string literal (cases `p` and `t`). This has been explained hundreds of times already. All the other cases have const in the right places (or more) so the compiler will warn you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *p = "Hello"
```

*"Hello"* is a string literal placed in implementation read only memory and modifying it in any possible way is an UB. Irrespective of where you put the `const` qualifier any attempt to modify the string literal is a UB. The correct way to represent this in C++ is:

```
const char *p = "Hello";
```

---

```
char *p = "Hello" ;
```

Pointer can be reseated but the string should not be modified.

```
const char *q = "Hello" ;
char const *s = "Hello" ;
```

The correct way to represent a pointer pointing to string literal in C++. The pointer can be reseated but the string should not be modified.

```
char * const t = "Hello" ;
```

Pointer cannot be reseated and the string should not be modified.

```
const char * const u = "Hello" ;
```

Pointer is constant so is the string.

Any attempt to modify the string in any of these is an UB.

Comment: Since the question is tagged C and is not tagged C++, shouldn't this answer describe the situation in C, as opposed to what is correct in C++? (the traditional answer to this is that C and C++ are almost the same for the C subset of C++. Well, if they are the same, one might as well explain the situation in C. Plus this particular question involves string literals and character literals, both of which have different types in C and in C++)

Comment: @PascalCuoq I am about to drill whatever Alok said into my head.If you feel anything about what he said is different for C,can you kindly put that in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

These two cases are undefined behavior:

```
char *p = "Hello" ;
*p = 'M' ;  // Undefined behavior: trying to modify a string literal.


char * const t = "Hello" ;
*t = 'M' ;  // Undefined behavior: trying to modify a string literal.
```